# Not able to compare objects in Java string getting appended to classname

Tags: java

I am comparing two objects in Java and have implemented equals and hashcode.

Though the objects are equal the comparison returns false.

I found that in the equals implementation it's printing the class of the two objects as different although they are same.

For one it prints: `com.salebuild.model.TechnologyProduct`
While for the other it prints: `com.salebuild.model.TechnologyProduct_$$_javassist_71`

So it fails in this condition in the equals method:

```
if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
{
    return false;
}
```

Unable to find why it's appending this string: `_$$_javassist_71`

How can I overcome this? Could anyone suggest?

Comment: You got your code instrumented with Javasssist. `_$$_javassist_71` means it's a proxy. Double check if you really need this object to be proxied. Basically `TechnologyProduct_$$_javassist_71` extends `TechnologyProduct`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `instanceof` to check if both objects are of the same class.

Here is the code Eclipse offers to check object equality:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof LdapUserDetails)) //check class here
        return false;

    // check fields for equality here
}
```

Comment: no need to precise  `if (obj == null)`   since `null instanceof OneObject` returns `false`

Comment: @Mik378, I can't say why Eclipse developers decided to explicitly include it in the template.

Comment: Maybe there is a possibility to indicate whether you want to use the `instanceof` methodology or `getClass` methodology in Eclipse assistant (I use IntelliJ, so I don't know). And for sure, `null.getClass()` would lead to a `NullPointerException`. So generation of `equals` might be more generic and easier to maintain with the explicit nullity check.

Answer (score 1):

I would write something like that instead:

```
if (!(this instanceof TechnologyProduct))
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Because usually is not the only condition in an equal() method.

Comment: right side of instanceof should be type , but you are passing an object instance. This will not work.